# How to print the length to specified input in the text box

Tags: javascript, html, perl, drop-down-menu, textbox

as i need to print according to the difference of the length (693 to
    712) as like mentioned in all line of sequences.if i entered length as 
    20  it  should print only the sequence which differs 20 and if i enter 
    text box value as 20 and dropdown selection is greater than it should 
    print the length of seuences which matches greater than twenty.

example.txt

```
GGATCACGAGGTCAGGAGAT (693 TO 712)   ATCTCCTGACCTCGTGATCC (3223 TO 3242)
CAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA (917 TO 936)   TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTG (2998 TO 3017)
GAAACCCCGTCTCTACTAAAAATACAAAAAA (737 TO 767)    TTTTTTGTATTTTTAGTAGAGACGGGGTTTC (3168 TO 3198)
```

perl

```
#!usr/local/bin/perl
open(IN,"/home/httpd/cgi-bin/r/example.txt")|| die("Cannot open file");
while(<IN>)
{
    if($_ =~ /^\w+\s+\((\d+)\s+[to]+\s+(\d+)\)/i )
    {
        $data=$_;

        $num1=$1;
        $num2=$2;
        $diff=($num2-$num1)+1;
        $str="a".$diff;
        #print $str;
        push(@$str,$data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are capturing value from client side, why you are concatenating `"a"` with `$diff` and adding 1 in `$diff`, but it will work well if provided values from the command line.

The values are stored in hash instead of array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $fh, '<', 'example.txt' or die "unable to open file: $!";
my %hash;
while(<$fh>){
my @seq=split(/\)\s+/,$_);
foreach(@seq)
   {
$_=$_.") ";
#print $_;
if($_ =~ /(\d+)\s*TO\s*(\d+)/i ){
       my $num1=$1;
       my  $num2=$2;
my $diff=($num2-$num1)+1;
$hash{$_}=$diff;

  }
}
}
close($fh);
#print Dumper(\%hash);
print "enter the number: \n";
chomp(my $num=<>);
if($num == 20){
foreach(keys %hash){
print "$_ => $hash{$_} \n" if($hash{$_} == 20);
}
}
elsif($num > 20){
foreach(keys %hash){
print "$_ => $hash{$_} \n" if($hash{$_} >  20);
}
}
```